# VBA Error Handling Issue with Blank Cells

Tags: vba, excel

This is a sample of a part of a table that I'm working with:[image]

This table is generated from some other VBA code. I wrote a simple script to clear the #VALUE terms from the table after it's generated.

```
'Clean any value errors before charting

    With Worksheets("CG Raw Data")

    On Error Resume Next

    Range("A2:W2").End(xlDown).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors).ClearContents

    On Error GoTo 0

    End With

End Sub
```

Now the table looks like:

[image]

For some reason this code clears the entire column if it has any blanks and not just the #VALUE errors. I want it to just delete the #VALUE errors and keep all other cells. As far as I can tell the code should be doing that. What is the error?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just wrap the formulas with `=IFERROR()`?

Comment: yup that would work - I was mostly just curious why the code was clearing the entire columns with blanks and how to avoid that for future reference

Comment: You could use the VBA function `IsError` instead. You would loop through all cells (with `For each cell in Range("A2:W2").End(xlDown)  ---  Next cell`) and check `If IsError(cell) Then  ---  End If`. This should not do anything for blank cells.

Comment: I am curious what is in those blank cells? Are they really blank? I tested this code against a range of my own and it worked perfectly.

Comment: It didn't clear `[Bear]` completely. Are the formulas in other columns somehow dependant on the formulas that are being deleted?

Comment: Is `Range("A2:W2").End(xlDown).` required? Wouldn't `Cells.SpecialCells(...` do exactly the same thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first recommendation would be to wrap the formulas with `=IFERROR(,"").`

Alternatively, something like this should work:

```
DIM rngCell as Range

For Each rngCell In Worksheets(1).Range("A1:W" & Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row)
    If IsError(rngCell) Then
        rngCell.Clear
    End If
Next rngCell
```

I'd imagine that the entire dataset is being cleared because you're checking the entire range and consiquently clearing it if any value contains an error.

*I don't have rep to leave a comment.*

Answer (score 0):

Issue #1 - you are `Withing` a specific worksheet, but not qualifying the `Range()`
Issue #2 - You will clear errors other than `#VALUE`
How about:

```
Sub NoValue()
    Dim r As Range, N As Long

    With Worksheets("CG Raw Data")
        N = .Cells(Rows.Count, "W").End(xlUp).Row
        For Each r In .Range("A2:W" & N)
            If r.Text = "#VALUE!" Then r.ClearContents
        Next r
    End With
End Sub
```